# Back in history react router (redux)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have an project, where I have lot of page components defined as this:

```
class ExamplePage extends Component<IProps, IState> {
    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {...something}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //Load all data with fetch/redux actions
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="example"></div>
        )
    }
}
```

If I have `ExamplePage1` and `ExamplePage2` both used in react router as this:

```
<Switch location={location}>
    <Route exact path='/first-path' component={ExamplePage1}/>
    <Route exact path='/second-path' component={ExamplePage2}/>
</Switch>
```

I'm using links inside examplepages with `NavLink` component.

My root is defined as this:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <ScrollToTop>
                <App />
            </ScrollToTop>
        </Router>
    </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

Everything works, every links works correctly. Problem is when I use back button in browser (chrome). Then for example if I'm in `ExamplePage2`, in `componentDidMount` every data is loaded to state and also to redux store. Then I click to navlink on that page, and I'm redirected to `ExamplePage1`. Then I click back button in browser (Chrome), and `ExamplePage2` is shown, BUT no data are loaded, looks like it is "mounted" somewhere in app history or something else ... do you see any concept issues there? Or how to fix my problem?